# How to use ConcealValueOnDocument on a field in email signature prefilled with values using c# eSign api

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using C# DocuSign API (envelope api) for email signature. I am sending a document with prefilled values to DocuSign. Question is -  Is it possible to set ConcealValueOnDocument on fields which are readonly so that fields will be hide with asterisks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the following C# snippet:

```
Text textTab1 = new Text {  ConcealValueOnDocument = "true", Required = "true", Locked = "true" /* add additional properties... */ };
```

However, I find this odd. If the recipients cannot modify, you can set the value to be "**********" and use a custom field for any sensitive information you want to send (so it's metadata in the envelope but not visible to anyone).

**ConcealValueOnDocument** was intended for situations where you have signer 1 enter their SSN and signer 2 enter their SSN, but you don't want them to see eachother's SSNs... (for example).